# How to get String from JSONObject without Specific Name

Tags: java, android, json

Please check this code sample.

```
HttpEntity getResponseEntity = getResponse.getEntity();

String message = EntityUtils.toString(getResponseEntity,"UTF-8");

//message = {"EntryPointJsonResult":"{\"NextTransactionUrl\":null,\"TraceId\":null,\"IsAuthorizationRequired\":false,\"IsError\":false,\"ErrorCode\":null,\"ErrorMessage\":null}"}

JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
String objectString = object.getString("EntryPointJsonResult"); 
//objectString = {\"NextTransactionUrl\":null,\"TraceId\":null,\"IsAuthorizationRequired\":false,\"IsError\":false,\"ErrorCode\":null,\"ErrorMessage\":null}
```

That's the question : I want to get the "objectString"  without "EntryPointJsonResult". Cause this information is different at the another response.

So how can I get the "objectString" without specific key like "EntryPointJsonResult"

Comment: You cannot. Fetching data without object name is allowed only in array

Comment: YOu can iterate the data and get all values in that.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You can get values of json object like this without knowing key

```
Iterator<String> keys= object.keys();
while (keys.hasNext()) 
{
        String keyValue = (String)keys.next();
        String valueString = object.getString(keyValue);
}
```

Comment: if there is a one element, this solution worked. But didn't work for nested json elements.

Comment: can you share your JSON String?

Comment: Something like that http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/189462/Nested-Json-Sample.

Sorry about that. Cause I didn't know the json was nested.

Comment: object.getJSONObject("objectString");

Comment: Okey but, we can not sure how many nested elements are there. So object.getJSONObject("objectString"); can give us another nested JsonObject. So maybe we can write a recursive method for that. But frankly, I don't want to deal with it. Cause it's not engineering. There is must be a shortcut for that like some library's method.

Thanks a lot for your interest anyway. Best Day.

Comment: Dear downvoters, I'd be grateful for any feedback or criticism that I can learn from or use to help me improve my answer

Answer (score 4):

This should work.

```
JSONObject object = new JSONObject(message);
String objectString = object.getString(object.names().get(0));
```

But it will only work if you sure that `NextTransactionUrl` node exists. By the way, in this case, this node could have another name, it will still work.

Comment: if there is a one element, this solution worked. But didn't work for nested json elements

Comment: Could you give an example ?

Comment: Something like that http://www.snip2code.com/Snippet/189462/Nested-Json-Sample.

Sorry about that. Cause I didn't know the json was nested.

Comment: I see. But it could have many level before getting your attribubtes. Maybe recursivity ?

Comment: I tihnk so. But I don't understand how there is not a method for that :D Interesting.